# reacting to radio buttons with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm searching for a possibility to react with jquery or js, when a radio button is selected.
My html

```
<div class="row" id="options2">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
        <input id="delivery" type="radio" name="option2" class="icheck">Lieferung</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
        <input id="takeaway" type="radio" name="option2" class="icheck">Abholung</input>
   </div>
</div>
```

I tried this solution

```
$("input[name='option2']").change(function(){
  console.log('test');
});
```

Are there other possibilities to achieve this?

Comment: Hey ...its working

Comment: what do you want...do you want to know which option was selected ?

Comment: $("input[name='option2']").change(function(){
  console.log( $(this).attr('id') );
});

Comment: "*Are there other possibilities to achieve this?*" - why? In what way does this fail, what problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: yes, i want to hide/show something when a radio button is pressed, i think the input selector does not work, but why? ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this

```
<div class="row" id="options2">
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
    <input id="delivery" type="radio" name="option2" value="1" class="icheck">Lieferung</input>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-6">
    <input id="takeaway" type="radio" name="option2" value="2" class="icheck">Abholung</input>
   </div>
</div>
```

and

```
$("input[name='option2']").change(function(){
  console.log($(this).val());
});
```

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, it seems below code could be work: $('input[type=radio][name=option2]').change(function() {
     if (this.value == '1') {
  alert("One checked");
     }
     else if (this.value == '2') {
  alert("Second checked");
     }
 });

Answer (score 0):

Uh, I missed icheck provided by the template, with the following code it works.
https://github.com/fronteed/icheck

```
$('#delivery').on('ifChecked', function(event){
    alert(event.type + ' callback');
  });
```